# Error 505 while installing on Lollipop devices

Tags: android, google-play, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am a developer and recently published my new application My VIT on Play Store. Everything is working fine except a small bug in Android Lollipop devices. Whenever my users are trying to install app from play store in their devices, they get a 505 during the time of installation.

The app is running well on Kitkat and many other Lollipop devices. Some devices like nexus 6, nexus 7 2013, htc one m8, yu yuphoria are facing problems. I contacted Google Support, but they provided me with solutions I already performed.

I have cleared my Play Store data, Play Services data, download manager data, reset my date/time and re-added my Google account. Still no luck. I think it's a development issue because my other app is running fine on those devices.

Comment: Hi there. I've paragraphed your question and tidied it up a bit. I've removed the URL of your project, and also the request to `git clone` it - Stack Overflow does not work like that. Please add the relevant code to your post so everything that readers need is in the question. I wonder whether this is broad enough that you really need a freelancer to do some remote consulting for a day or two?

Comment: A deleted answer [provided this link](http://appslova.com/android-fix-unknown-error-code-application-install-505-error-505/) - I don't know if that is helpful.